# Is it possible to download a file that requires authentication using SaltStack's file.managed state?

Tags: authentication, salt-stack

I've been reading through the [`file.managed` documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3005/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) and there are plenty of examples of downloading files from URLs. However, none of these examples mention using any forms of authentication such as a username and password. I already know about `cmd.run`, I am specifically asking about the `file.managed` module.

Is it possible to download files that require authentication using this module?

Here is an example cURL command that I want to implement using the `file.managed` state module instead:

```
curl -L -u "username:password" -O https://mywebsite.com/important_file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [standard URI authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) is supported:

```yaml
download file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /target
    - source: https://username:password@mywebsite.com/important_file.tar.gz
```

You'll probably want to template the password in from pillar/sdb to reduce its exposure.

This will work for any state that uses source URLs, including `archive.extracted`.